# Cannot delete encrypted CoreStorage external hard drive with macOS

Tags: macos, external-hard-drive, filevault

I have a 2TB Time Machine external HDD, encrypted with FileVault, that I use that I pulled out without ejecting.

The drive would then stop showing when I plug it back in and so I've tried to just wipe it in several ways.

I have read nearly everything:

- tried looking for `fsck` running (it's not, it probably was initially before I started messing about), have tried using DiskUtility but the drive is greyed out and just crashes Disk Utility.
- Tried running First Aid / Repair - it gets far and then just fails at the end.
- I have run `diskutil` many times to try and just completely wipe the drive and reformat it but that never works.
- I have run `diskutil cs list` and identified the coreStorage volume and deleted that - always fails after a while with `"Error: -69783: Unable to delete the CoreStorage Logical Volume Group".`
- I have tried to unmount / mount and then run the commands
- I have tried all the above first unlocking the drive when the GUI pops up to put in my password, and *also* when just cancelling that popup.
- I have tried using Paragon NTFS to wipe it, no dice there either.

I basically can't seem to wipe this drive and start using it again as a Time Machine backup!

Is there any way using Mac / Windows / whatever to just fully wipe it and reset it to normal :(

Comment: What OS are you running? `diskutil cs list` would suggest something older than Mojave. Have you tried the old "switch it all off then back on again"? Power off the drive, shut down the Mac, power on the drive, boot the Mac. See  Disk Utility again (make sure you're in device view, not volume view).

Comment: I'm running Big Sur, and have shut down many times :(

Comment: Then why are you using `cs list`? Core storage went away with High Sierra or Mojave. Did you check device view?

Comment: I have no idea mate, just looking at stuff I've found online to try and figure out what's going on. I made the Time Machine backup on a fresh new HDD in April so that would have been Catalina...my Disk Utility is set to show all devices yeah

Comment: Then what happens if you simply try to Erase the device, rather than try to format any specific partition? btw, on Mojave & later, just use `diskutil list` rather than cs list.